# Can I reopen closed panes in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

[Related, but this is Gnome Terminal, not Screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187902/reopen-a-last-closed-tab-in-gnome-terminal)

I closed a "tab" (pane? window? not sure the correct term) within my screen session. Is there a way to recover a "tab" lost in this way?

(not dissimilar ctrl+shift+t in a browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Once a shell session has terminated, it is gone, no matter whether it was running in GNU `screen`, in `tmux`, in a terminal emulator or directly on a console.

A web browser is different as it's able to just reload the page in a new tab if you ask it to reopen the most recently closed tab.  A browser may additionally keep track of data that you may have entered into forms etc. before closing the tab, and restore this too.  GNU `screen` does nothing of that.

Comment: As I feared. Thank you. No large loss, but wanted to be sure. Will "accept" tomorrow.